# Drawing simple shapes or using sprites with OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, drawing, opengl-es-2.0, sprite

I want to create a simple shape, let's say, a circle, it might have transparency, colors, etc. but it's still a simple circle.

In every tutorial I see, people use sprites. I am not sure what should I use for my case.

Should I use a sprite with a circle or should I try and draw the shape myself?

What are the advantages of each method?

Is there a line dividing them or is it just experience to know which one to use?

Comment: You'll need a framework on top of OpenGL to draw shapes efficiently. OpenGL = low level graphics (triangles, textures); shapes and sprites = high level graphics.

Comment: On top of that, there's OpenVG for drawing shapes.

Comment: Yes, I do use AndEngine as a framework on top os OpenGL-ES 2, but there is always still the option of using the GL without the sprite framework for example... What I don't know is if it's the right thing to always use sprites or manually draw simple shapes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU geometry is composed of triangles or line segments so it'll be inefficient to draw a circle in this way, it'll require too many triangles for it to look smooth.

The two more efficient ways to do that are:

1. Use a sprite
2. Use a shader and draw the circle. Check [ShaderToy](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/), more specifically the "Shapes" preset.